# facebook connect + Phonegap

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I followed the phonegap plugin to integrate facebook using

https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect#ios-mac-os-x

It works well.But when I try to make the build or ipa file for my iOS app, it is always shown in the organizer window as mac app archive.How can I use this plugin for iOS app builds? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had mistakenly added all the files provided which were really of no use.I removed the unused ones and it worked.